# Const array change

Tags: javascript

I got the problem with `tempOccupiedMonths`

```
this.occupiedMonths = [];
for (let index = 0; index < this.startMonth; index++){
        this.occupiedMonths.push(index)
      }
      for (let index = this.endMonth+1; index<=34; index++){
        this.occupiedMonths.push(index)
      }
      const tempOccupiedMonths = this.occupiedMonths
```

E.g From January to March, tempOccupiedMonths = this.occupiedMonths = [3,4,5,...,34]

```
this.occupiedMonths.push(0, 1, 2);
```

Then

```
this.occupiedMonths=tempOccupiedMonths
```

I expected tempOccupiedMonths still [3,4,5,...,34] but tempOccupiedMonths = this.occupiedMonths = [0,1,2,...,34]. Why is that and how I solve this problem. Thankyou

Comment: Assigning an array reference from one variable to another does not make a copy of the array.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a `Shallow copy of this.occupiedMonths` instead of `Deep copy of this.occupiedMonths` So both `this.occupiedMonths and tempOccupiedMonths are sharing same address in memory`

**Try this**

```
const tempOccupiedMonths=[...this.occupiedMonths]
```

Hope it will help you

For more information about js `spread syntax` follow this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Assigning one array reference to another variable will make both variables point to the same array, i.e. modifications of the array are reflected by both variables. You can create a shallow copy of the array using `slice`.

```
const tempOccupiedMonths = this.occupiedMonths.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do array assign directly as tempOccupiedMonths = this.occupiedMonths = [3,4,5,...,34] .Because they are referencing. Equal area without reference follow steps in the below. We are using **spread operator** **[...this.occupiedMonths]**

spread operator: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-rest-spread/

1. tempOccupiedMonths =  [3,4,5,...,34];
2. tempOccupiedMonths = [...this.occupiedMonths];

The solution example is in the below

```js
let firstArray = [];
let secondArray = [];

firstArray = secondArray = [3, 4, 5];

console.log(`firstArray: ${firstArray}`);   // firstArray: 3,4,5
console.log(`secondArray: ${secondArray}`); // secondArray: 3,4,5

firstArray.push(1, 2, 3);

console.log(`firstArray: ${firstArray}`);   // firstArray: 3,4,5,1,2,3
console.log(`secondArray: ${secondArray}`);  // secondArray: 3,4,5,1,2,3

// ========================================

secondArray = [3, 4, 5];
firstArray = [...secondArray];

console.log(`firstArray: ${firstArray}`);   // firstArray: 3,4,5
console.log(`secondArray: ${secondArray}`); // secondArray: 3,4,5

firstArray.push(1, 2, 3);

console.log(`firstArray: ${firstArray}`);   // firstArray: 3,4,5,1,2,3
console.log(`secondArray: ${secondArray}`);  // secondArray: 3,4,5 <-**** no reference ****
```